Bun/Vite build failing in GitHub Actions/Ubuntu — “undefined” error message
When I run it on my Mac, bunx --bun vite build does this:
vite v5.4.2 building for production...
✓ 2951 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                     1.03 kB │ gzip:   0.56 kB
dist/assets/index-BifuYEoc.css     38.29 kB │ gzip:   8.03 kB
dist/assets/index-BG4aLjCM.js   3,571.02 kB │ gzip: 649.00 kB
✓ built in 3.08s

From a GitHub Actions workflow:
vite v5.4.2 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 347 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 3.12s
error during build:
undefined
error: script "build" exited with code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

undefined.  That’s very helpful.  Presumably, it’s the error message...
This used to work. The only thing I can think of that changed is I added vite.config.ts:
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import graphqlLoader from "vite-plugin-graphql-loader";
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), graphqlLoader(), tsconfigPaths()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
  }
});

How can I debug this?

tl;dr: it was a problem with the letter-case on the name of a file.
I asked ChatGPT for some help and, on a very long list of other ideas, it suggested I check for case-sensitivity problems.  This resonated because a few days ago, I had corrected a file named editLinkDialog.tsx to EditLinkDialog.tsx.  Perhaps that was the issue.
I verified on my Mac that the file was named correctly.
I thought that the key difference between the Mac and the GitHub Actions workflow might be the underlying OS. I started an Ubuntu 22.4 server up on AWS EC2, an environment fairly similar to Actions’s, and managed to get it set up to build my app.
I got the same error: error during build: undefined!  Not helpful in itself, but now the problem was occurring from the command-line, where I could interact with it closely.
With no particular expectations, I started up Bun as a REPL:
% bun repl
Welcome to Bun v1.1.26
Type ".help" for more information.
>

and I ran the build manually:
> import vite from "vite"
undefined
> await vite.build()
vite v5.4.2 building for production...
✓ 2441 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 1.97s
ENOENT: [vite:load-fallback] 
Could not load src/components/EditLinkDialog: No such file or directory

Bun or at Vite was swallowing the actual error message.
I fixed the case of the file on Ubuntu and pushed that, and the problem went away.
